# How to get the content from duplicate xml tags that has data in it

Tags: xml, tags, duplicates

I have below xml data with duplicate tags for CONS_BILL_NUMBER, one has null value and another has not null value.

XML data:

```
           <G_ITEM>
              <PAYMENT_ID>2020</PAYMENT_ID>
              <CONS_BILL_NUMBER></CONS_BILL_NUMBER>
              <TYPE>TEST</TYPE>
              <TRX_DATE>01-JUN-14</TRX_DATE>
              <DUE_DATE>01-JUL-14</DUE_DATE>
              <CURRENCY_B>USD</CURRENCY_B>
              <ORIGINAL_AMOUNT>2800</ORIGINAL_AMOUNT>
              <BALANCE_DUE>2800</BALANCE_DUE>
              <CONS_BILL_NUMBER>33333</CONS_BILL_NUMBER>
              <CD_ORIGINAL_AMOUNT>        2,800.00 </CD_ORIGINAL_AMOUNT>
              <CD_BALANCE_DUE>        2,800.00 </CD_BALANCE_DUE>
            </G_ITEM>
```

XSL code:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//G_MAIN">
<xsl:for-each select=".//G_ITEM">
 <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="13.6875">          
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select=".//ancestor-or-self::*/COLLECTOR"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select=".//ancestor-or-self::*/NAME"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select=".//ancestor-or-self::*/NUMBER_A"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select=".//ancestor-or-self::*/LOCATION"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="CONS_BILL_NUMBER"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="TYPE"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="TRX_DATE"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="DUE_DATE"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="CURRENCY_B"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="CD_ORIGINAL_AMOUNT"/></Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="CD_BALANCE_DUE"/></Data></Cell>
 </Row>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

The xsl code is returning the null value as it is taking the first tag  and not the 33333.

Please help to parse this xml to get the second xml tag  that has a value in it.

Thanks
Vishnu

Comment: Hi Vishnu, Why are using such duplicate tag in xml. It will create difficulties while parsing. I think you can do a patch like remove the null value tag or swap the order of two same tag in xml values.

Comment: Hi Janty, The source of the xml data is not in my control. It is coming from an oracle report. please let me know how to remove the null value tag

Comment: Just do a simple way of replace the empty tag with empty string.

Comment: The below code worked for me:                                                                              <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="CONS_BILL_NUMBER/following-sibling::*[7]"/></Data></Cell>